# Variable is listed by `info vars` but can't be accessed

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to write a TclOO wrapper around the http package. The idea is to create an object passing the arguments that you would normally pass to `http::geturl` and have `code`, `data`, `ncode` and `meta` methods to return the same data as the corresponding `http::` proc. To avoid lots of typing, I hit upon the following:

```
oo::class create myHttp {
    constructor {url args} {
    set responses {data code ncode meta}
    foreach response $responses {
        oo::objdefine [self object] variable -append m_$response
        oo::objdefine [self object] method $response {} [subst -nocommands {
 puts stdout [lsort [info vars *]]
            return [set m_$response]
        }]
    }

    set tok [http::geturl $url {*}$args]
    foreach response $responses {
        set m_$response [http::$response $tok]
    }

    http::cleanup $tok
}
```

Sadly it doesn't work.

```
% set h [myHttp new http://www.google.co.uk]
% $h code
m_code m_data m_meta m_ncode
can't read "m_code": no such variable
```

What's going on here? The output of [info vars] suggests that `m_code` exists, but the error says it doesn't. Accessing the variables directly from the `[info object namespace $h]` namespace shows that they all exist and have the expected values but all the accessor methods fail with the same error.

Is there a better way to "auto-generate" the methods and variables? I freely admit that I haven't quite got my head around defining methods using `oo::objdefine` rather than in an `oo::class create` statement, and I've tried adding, semi-randomly, `my variable m_$response` and `variable m_$response` statements in the `$reponse` methods to no avail. I'm concerned to find myself using `subst` here as I've usually found on later review that a simple `list` would have worked adequately and less opaquely.

For completeness, I'm using Tcl 8.6.4 using an ActiveState distribution on Windows 7, and debugging with TkCon.

Comment: Note that `info vars` will report variable names after they have been named by a `variable` command even if they do not exist yet and are considered "no such variable".

Comment: That would happen if the entry exists in the relevant variable table, but it's contents are non-existent at the point of reading (typically because it's a NULL pointer; Tcl reports those the same for most things as if the variable isn't there at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write it as

```
oo::class create myHttp {
    variable tok
    constructor {url args} {
        set tok [http::geturl $url {*}$args]
        foreach response {data code ncode meta} {
            oo::objdefine [self] forward $response http::$response $tok
        }

    }
    destructor {
        http::cleanup $tok
    }
}
```

but if you really need the variables for some purpose, that obviously won't work.

Comment: Thanks Peter. That does the trick very nicely. I don't need the variables and hadn't previously looked at the `forward` subcommand.

Comment: `forward` lets you do neat stuff. In particular, it resolves its target command in the context of the instance namespace, so class-level forwards can use instance-defined information. This lets you do sneakily-powerful stuff with almost no code (it's how I wrap Tk widgets when I make megawidgets, though there's a bunch of other tricks required too).